How can I send the error frame (Bit stuff error, CRC, CRC Delimiter) through the Canalyzer IG window manually
I want to send the error frame through the Canalyzer other than changing the baud rate,
How can we send the CAN frame with the errors like CRC, bit stuffing etc. through the Canalyzer IG window manually.
I had tried sending an error frame which comes under the special frame from IG window and it worked, but I want to send the frame manually by creating frame with error induced in it.
